# Is there a way to change the attribute of an object assigned to the attribute of another object?

Tags: python

I'd like to change the attribute of an object that has been assigned as an attribute of another object.

```
cageNumber = int(input('Cage number: '))
mouseNumber = int(input('Mouse number: '))
mouseID = f'm{mouseNumber}'
setattr(cages[cageNumber].mouseID, 'sacrificed', True)
```

The cage is an instance of a class and each cage has 5 attributes. Each mouse is an instance of a class and they are assigned as the attributes of the cage object. The cages are contained in a dictionary.

My cage has no attribute named `mouseID`, but it DOES have 5 attributes named
`m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4`, and `m5`. These are solved by `mouseID = f'm{mouseNumber}'`.

I'd like to do something like this: `cage[101].m3.sacrificed = True` for each of 5 mice
(m1 - m5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, you need to use a call to `getattr()` to get the attribute by name as a string. Also, I don't really see a reason to use `setattr()` here.

```
getattr(cages[cageNumber], mouseID).sacrificed = True
```

Although if you're doing this sort of thing a lot (and even if you're not), it would probably be less cumbersome to put `m1`, `m2`, etc. into a list or dict for easier indexing, so you can instead do something like:

```
cages[cageNumber].mice[mouseID].sacrificed = True
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I'll do! Thank you!